# How to use a private gitlab docker registry to pull images from in production?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a local registry hosting my images and I need to be able to pull images from it on a production server during deployment. I figured I could use a reverse SSH tunnel to allow the server's docker instance to contact my local server:

```
ssh -R 5050:localhost:5050 user@prod \
  "echo '127.0.0.1 registry.local' >> /etc/hosts;
   docker login -u gitlabuser -p gitlabpassword registry;
   docker pull..."
```

However, it looks like `docker login` actually gets redirected to `:443` on the server to get a login token. I *could* also have a reverse tunnel to point to `:443` on the local server, but this seems like a security nightmare. There must be another way to get this working.

Alternatively, I may just use `docker save` and push the images to my server manually.

Comment: This feels like a situation where you should ask _why_ you want to do this. Is your registry in an air gapped environment? If so, why are you pulling code _out_ of it? 

If it isn't enforced air gapped why not just have direct access to your registry?

Comment: @JJAsghar isn't there some middle ground between those two extremes? My code and registry are on my local network, which I don't want to overly expose to the internet. I also don't want to move my registry to my cloud hosting provider so I can save on yet another server to pay for.

Comment: Great question, and honestly "it depends" is the only real answer here. There are multiple ways to run "private" registries now, (most have some cost associated with them) and wouldn't require another server to pay for. I completlely understand not exposing your internal/home network to the internet, but you have to balance the complexity of your deployment. 
IIRC, quay.io and dockerhub allow for _one_ free private registry, so you could push to one of them?